# Activity Bundle , when it would be lost?

Tags: android

When OS will completely forget the state about an Activity and all information relate to an Activity ( any records about an Activity) ?

In other words when it will make Bundle to be a new instance?

I found the below explanation but it does not explain this "Killing bundle" point?

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29

> Called to retrieve per-instance state from an activity before being killed so that the state can be restored in onCreate(android.os.Bundle) or onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle) (the android.os.Bundle populated by this method will be passed to both).
>   This method is called before an activity may be killed so that when it comes back some time in the future it can restore its state. For example, if activity B is launched in front of activity A, and at some point activity A is killed to reclaim resources, activity A will have a chance to save the current state of its user interface via this method so that when the user returns to activity A, the state of the user interface can be restored via onCreate(android.os.Bundle) or onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle).
>   Do not confuse this method with activity lifecycle callbacks such as onPause(), which is always called when an activity is being placed in the background or on its way to destruction, or onStop() which is called before destruction. One example of when onPause() and onStop() is called and not this method is when a user navigates back from activity B to activity A: there is no need to call onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle) on B because that particular instance will never be restored, so the system avoids calling it. An example when onPause() is called and not onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle) is when activity B is launched in front of activity A: the system may avoid calling onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle) on activity A if it isn't killed during the lifetime of B since the state of the user interface of A will stay intact.
>   The default implementation takes care of most of the UI per-instance state for you by calling android.view.View.onSaveInstanceState() on each view in the hierarchy that has an id, and by saving the id of the currently focused view (all of which is restored by the default implementation of onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)). If you override this method to save additional information not captured by each individual view, you will likely want to call through to the default implementation, otherwise be prepared to save all of the state of each view yourself.
>   If called, this method will occur before onStop(). There are no guarantees about whether it will occur before or after onPause().

Answer (score 1):

There are many cases where this could occur:

> Here is a [small topic](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) on reference mentioning different
>   use-cases about recreating activities.

If you want more control over the application life cycle:

> Take a look a the [application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) object for more information.

Personal advice:

> I think you should not care about when/what, This is something the
>   android system will manage for you, your code should be optimized to
>   handle all usecases (when the bundle will be null or not). A bundle
>   should only be used to handle state-keeping, if you want to
>   persist data you should take a look at fileI/O, SQLlite or shared
>   preference.

Comment: in configuration changes , yes no doubt .We could use set retain to true in Fragments and deal too. What would last longer Bundle or retained fragment ? this was the case I got this question to asses about when Bundle would destroy forever

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I believe they will last the same amount, they will be initialized until a condition occurs that requires the system to release resources (e.g. low memmorry method in application object).  Only a Google employee working on the framework itself will be able to give you a full answer. But personally i believe ,as a developer, that you should not care about it, as long as you handle all use-cases in code